# "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames" when clicking on "Question advertisement" in sidebar

Tags: bug, advertising

In the side bar on the right, I saw a cross-site "ad" for a [Music question with an interesting title](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/78491/what-is-the-name-for-a-chord-with-two-suspensions).

I clicked the ad, then was met by a browser alert with the warning

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames

And the weird thing is, when I clicked the alert button, the ad was momentarily replaced with what appeared to be the top-left corner of the page I was on, then I was redirected to the front page of SO.

This is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265627/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-on), but has only happened the once, when I clicked on the ad. I have been unable to reproduce it by clicking on other ads.

I'm on Chrome "Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

---

Our internet is awful right now (1.5mbps download!), and has been for a couple hours. Shaw's derping hard. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. I wouldn't think that it would, but I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: What kind of ad was it? The 320x320 image ad, a listing in Hot Network Questions, or something else?

Comment: @NathanTuggy A fairly large, square ad, and by context, ya, it was advertising a Hot question.