# Clicking a HNQ "ad" in the sidebar opens the link in the ad instead of changing the current page

Tags: bug, hot-questions, sidebar

[I tried to report this awhile ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322127/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-wh), but I didn't have evidence of it, so it was dismissed. I'm not crazy though, and here's proof!:

[image: Bug GIF]

When clicking on a HNQ in the side-bar, the link appears to open within the ad itself (an iframe? I'm not a web-dev so I'm not sure the terminology).

This happens *consistently*. I can't reproduce it often because the ads don't appear very often. *Every time* I try to reproduce it though, I'm able.

This was done on Edge 44.18362.329.0, but as the link above shows, a year ago I did it in Chrome.

Comment: @Nick Damn. Good catch.

Comment: (Y) my memory doesn't always serve me this well :p